# Not able to set soap header for user authentication in php

Tags: php, authentication, soap, soap-client

My complete soap strucute is as follows :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:uw="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/HCM/services/UW_STBIO_REQ.V1">
  <soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:Username>XXXXXXXX</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXXXXX</wsse:Password>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
 </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <uw:UW_STBIO_REQ>
    <uw:EMPLID>428864</uw:EMPLID>
  </uw:UW_STBIO_REQ>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My PHP code is :

```
<?php
$studentFeesInformationObj = new soapclient("wsdl/QAGetStudentBioInformation.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$security = array( 'UsernameToken' => array(
                                                'Username'=>'XXXXXXXX',
                                                'Password'=>'XXXXXXXX'    
                                            )
                                        );

$header = new SoapHeader('wsse','Security',$security, false);
$studentFeesInformationObj->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$params = array('EMPLID' => '428864');

try{
    $result = $studentFeesInformationObj->__soapCall('UW_STUDBIO_SO', array('parameters' => $params));
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "<pre>$e<br>";
    echo "REQUEST HEADERS:\n" . $studentFeesInformationObj->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "\n";
    print_r($studentFeesInformationObj);    
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($result); 

?>
```

Now, when I try using any rest client like in my case chrome plugin, its working fine but when I try to so same using PHP, its not working, I'm getting following response :

```
SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server] BEA-380001: Internal Server Error in /var/www/html/nusoap-0.9.5/client.php:20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#114976):

```
class WsseAuthHeader extends SoapHeader {

private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
private $wsu_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd';

function __construct($user, $pass) {

    $created = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $nonce = mt_rand();
    $passdigest = base64_encode( pack('H*', sha1( pack('H*', $nonce) . pack('a*',$created).  pack('a*',$pass))));

    $auth = new stdClass();
    $auth->Username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
    $auth->Password = new SoapVar($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
    $auth->Nonce = new SoapVar($passdigest, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);
    $auth->Created = new SoapVar($created, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wsu_ns);

    $username_token = new stdClass();
    $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns);

    $security_sv = new SoapVar(
        new SoapVar($username_token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns),
        SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns);
    parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
}
}
```

And create header like this :

```
$client->__setSoapHeaders(Array(new WsseAuthHeader("user", "pass")));
```